# SSH keeps timing out when trying to connect to remote server

Tags: ssh, remote-access, ssh-tunnel, timeout

I am trying to connect to a remote server via ssh. I have done it previously without any problem. However, recently, most of the time when I ping it, it just says "request timed out" - there are only a few times where I have gotten it to work. I'm guessing it is quite difficult to connect to the IP that I'm trying to connect to because I have to use ZeroTier One for SSH tunnelling.

I have also tried turning off the firewall but it doesn't seem to yield consistent results. It seems that the times it times out are mostly random, and if I get lucky, it works for a short time. I did a trace and this was the output.

```
  1    19 ms     4 ms     9 ms  192.168.12.1
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 25     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 26     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 27     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 28     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 29     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Trace complete.
```

Update: The most reliable (still not very reliable) method I've tried so far was flushing the DNS and resetting the IP. But it doesn't work over half the time and I have to restart my computer every time to only ssh for a few minutes.

Update: Now even flushing the DNS doesn't work. Every time it gives "destination host unreachable" or request timed out. I can't get it to work a single time.

Does anyone have any ideas on why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide some information about your network - routes, networks, source and destination IPs etc.

Comment: Check the logs on the destination server and check if the ssh port is listening also run sshd -T